# Seeking SLOW encrypt/decrypt method or library

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm trying to protect data that a user submits on a series of notecards. The encryption/decryption will (hopefully) occur in-browser, so the user controls as much of the securing process as possible.

I found an AES library (https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes) which is awesome. Unfortunately, I'm relying on users to create the encryption key, so I would like a MUCH slower algorithm. There are many hashing libraries (like PHPPass for PHP), but I need something bi-directional.

I'm open to other ideas, as well. I just need to find a solution.

Comment: Can they not create the encryption key before the encryption starts, or am I misunderstanding your desire for a slow encryption?

Comment: Sorry if this isn't relevant, but did you look at http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ ? Seems like it has a lot of great options. I don't know why you'd want it to be slower ... if you really want "slow" maybe use setTimeout or something for additional delay?

Comment: why would you ever want a slower algorithm?

Comment: @jbabey In general, to slow down brute force attacks enough to make them infeasible. Though I find it hard to imagine a use case for this assuming state-of-the-art encryption.

Comment: @delnan: that wouldn't be the algorithm, it would be the key derivation function. You're correct that brute force isn't really a concern for AES with proper keys, but you can add difficulty to the password -> key step.

Comment: I think you guys are dead on. I don't know how to hide the key creation from an attacker, but if I can, then I don't need anything to be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the encryption algorithm with [key derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). You don't want your encryption algorithm to be slow, as AES isn't at risk for brute forcing with proper keys.

Presumably since you say "users create the encryption key", you mean it's a scheme using passwords for keys? [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) is the recommended approach, and is approved by [NIST in SP800-132](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-132/nist-sp800-132.pdf)

Since you have this tagged Javascript, it looks like [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#PBKDF2) supports PBKDF2

When you get a password/passphrase from the user, you'll want to generate a salt and derive the actual AES key from PBKDF2. It doesn't need to be bi-directional, in that the same inputs (password, salt, and number of rounds) will always generate the same key.

Note that not even this is a properly designed cryptosystem. You shouldn't use AES without [CBC or CTR mode](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Block_Modes_and_Padding), and you still need to MAC your data (or use [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), which will take care of both).

Comment: Wow, I'm going to have to look up some of this. CBC will be used. Wouldn't the salt/hashing algo be known to an attacker making that part meaningless? Can you look at the github project I posted and let me know how that stacks up?

Comment: Also, crypto-js looks really good. I just want to understand the key derivation process and what risks it has. Tagged JS because I want to decrypt/encrypt client-side to help make this more secure.

Comment: Sorry, I just gave links to everything :). Security doesn't really depend on keeping the algorithms or the salt secret. All PBKDF2 really does is take a password, apply a hash a few thousand times, and use that as the key. If someone wanted to brute force, they'd have to do those few thousand hashes for every password they tried, which slows things down considerably. The salt just makes the process unique, so that if both you and I use 'password' as our password, but different salts, we get different keys. This prevents attackers from pre-computing huge lists (rainbow tables).

Comment: When doing client side crypto in Javascript, there's a lot of other precautions you need to take. See the article "Javascript crypto considered harmful" for the caveats (http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/).

Comment: Awesome. So the 'slow' part of this is the key creation, not the encrypting/decrypting. That's what slows down the brute-forcing. So, a strong password is still required. I'll check up on the article you linked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, exactly. Once you have a "strong" key, you want things to go as fast as possible. One of the reasons AES was selected was for performance. You only want to pay that slow penalty once, not for every block of data.

Comment: It sounds like the main risk is that if the server is compromised that someone can send the user code that would reveal the information I'm trying to protect. This seems like an at least slightly better outcome than just having plaintext in a database on the same server, no? Great article. I'm going to reread that several times.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20533/discussion-between-mfanto-and-stephane)